# How do you prove that the limit of this function does not exist?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

So I've been trying to figure out how this professor did this proof in which he had to prove that the limit of $sin\frac{π}{2x}$ as $x$ approaches 0 does not exist.

Could someone go over the steps he did and why he was able to do what he did?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QuJW.jpg

Comment: You'd better type it here using mathjax if you want to have a better chance of getting an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, they show if we take $\varepsilon = 1$, than given **any** $\delta > 0$ we can find $y,z \in (0,\delta)$ such that $h(z) = 1, h(y) = -1$.

This fact shows there can't be $L \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $L$ is the limit (because give $\varepsilon = 1$, there exists no $\delta > 0$ such that $|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |h(x)-L|< \varepsilon = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$f(x)
=\sin\frac{π}{2x}
$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

If
$x = \frac1{2n}$,
then
$f(x)
=\sin\frac{π}{2(1/(2n))}
=\sin(\pi n)
=0
$.

If
$x = \frac1{4n+1}$,
then
$f(x)
=\sin\frac{π}{2(1/(4n+1))}
=\sin(\pi (2n+\frac12))
=1
$.

For these two sequences 
approaching $0$,
the limits exists and
are different.
Therefore tha function
has no limit as
$x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the limit does not exist it is enough to show that $\lim {x \rightarrow 0^+}$ does not exist.

$z:= \dfrac {π}{2x}$.

Consider $\lim_{z \rightarrow  + \infty } \sin(z)$.

1) Choose $z_n = nπ,$  $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

$y_n:= \sin (z_n) = 0,$ for all $n$.

2) Choose $z_n = π/2 +2πn$.

$y_n= \sin(z_n) = 1$, for all $n$.

1)$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0.$

2) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = 1.$

Limit does not exist.